# How do you attribute a quote to a person/piece of work in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

Ex: "If you prick us do we not bleed? If you tickle us do we not laugh? If you poison us do we not die? And if you wrong us, shall we not revenge?"
The Merchant of Venice, by William Shakespeare

I know about the basic way, using という, but I was wondering if there were others I should know of, as well

Comment: ウィリアム・シェイクスピアの『ヴェニスの商人』に登場する言葉（名言）である

Comment: Can you give us an example with という so we know what you want to say?

Comment: [曰{いわ}く](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9B%B0%E3%81%8F) could also be used to refer to what someone has said, though I'm not sure if it could be used when quoting a fictional person.